# how to let maven recognize JAVA_HOME variable value?

Tags: java, maven

i have installed maven and although i put the JAVA_HOME variable value, maven continues to tell me this error :

[image]

i added the java_home variable value like this :

[image]

Comment: Remove the \bin

Comment: i removed it but  the java_home variable does not appears when i run the command `mvn --version` apart the runtime option is there  and it is `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre`

Comment: The directory provided should have a "bin\java.exe" binary.  Only you can look at your file structure and say what the proper value is.